# How can I delete data from state in React?

Tags: reactjs, state

When the user presses the add button, addCInputGroup runs and adds newCInputGroup. What I want to do is to be able to delete the dataValues ​​that the user clicked on. When I try this way, it deletes all the dataValues ​​that I clicked on and below it, not just the one I clicked on.

```
  const addCInputGroup = (type, chart) => {
    const newCInputGroup = (
      <CInputGroup className="mb-3" size="sm" key={Math.random()}>
        <CButton type="button" color="secondary" onClick={() => removeCInputGroup(type, chart, newCInputGroup.key)}>
          <i className="bi bi-trash icon-bg"></i>
        </CButton>
        <CFormSelect id="inputGroupSelect01">
          <option>Choose...</option>
          <option value="1">One</option>
          <option value="2">Two</option>
          <option value="3">Three</option>
        </CFormSelect>
      </CInputGroup>
    );

    if (type === 'dataValues') {
      setCollapseVisibleDataValues(true);

      // Update the dataValues property of the chart
      const updatedChart = {
        ...chart, // Copy the original chart data
        dataValues: [...chart.dataValues, newCInputGroup], // Add the new data value
      };

      // Find the index of the chart in the chartData array
      const chartIndex = chartData.findIndex((c) => c.chartName === chart.chartName);

      // Create a copy of the chartData array and update the chart at the found index
      const updatedChartData = [...chartData];
      updatedChartData[chartIndex] = updatedChart;

      // Update the state with the new chart data
      setChartData(updatedChartData);
      setChartDataValues([...chartDataValues, newCInputGroup]);
    } else if (type === 'dataCategories') {
      setCollapseVisibleDataCategories(true);
      setChartDataCategories([...chartDataCategories, newCInputGroup]);
    }
  };

  const removeCInputGroup = (type, chart, key) => {
    if (type === 'dataValues') {
      // Filter out the dataValues with the specified key
      const updatedDataValues = chart.dataValues.filter((inputGroup) => inputGroup.key !== key);

      // Update the chart's dataValues property
      const updatedChart = {
        ...chart,
        dataValues: updatedDataValues,
      };

      // Find the index of the chart in the chartData array
      const chartIndex = chartData.findIndex((c) => c.chartName === chart.chartName);

      // Create a copy of the chartData array and update the chart at the found index
      const updatedChartData = [...chartData];
      updatedChartData[chartIndex] = updatedChart;

      // Update the state with the new chart data
      setChartData(updatedChartData);
    } else if (type === 'dataCategories') {
    }
  };
```